# Convert exponential number to normal number using javascript after reading the data from csv file

Tags: javascript

I'm converting csv file data into json object. While converting csv file data to json object if I have a number more than the length of 15 digits it's converted automatically to exponential number. I need to convert this exponential number to normal number using Javascript.

I don't want to change CSV cell formatting, I want to convert using only javascript

Expected Output:

```
123456789012345
```

Current output:

```
1.23457E+14
```

Comment: Perhaps look into BigInt (currently in stage 3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) or a library which allows you to use large integers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number.toFixed()` function.

Comment: How would that work? `Number.parseFloat(Number.MAX_VALUE).toFixed(0)` produces `"1.7976931348623157e+308"`

Comment: It would work normally until 20 :) . I dont think he'll ever need more than that and if so he can use BigInt as you wrote down bellow.

Comment: Up to 1e+20 the `toFixed` call is not needed. Try `parseInt("100000000000000000000")`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `BigInt`.

Just call the constructor with the string value from the csv:

```
BigInt("123456789")
```

The following code snippet illustrates the difference in parsing/printing large integers as numbers or BigInts:

```js
console.log("max number value : " + Number.MAX_VALUE);

console.log("max number value in non-scientific notation: " + BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE));

console.log("max number value parsed as Int: " + parseInt(BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE).toString()));

console.log("max number value parsed as BigInt: " + BigInt(BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE).toString()));

console.log("10x max number value parsed as Int: " + parseInt(BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE).toString() + '0'));

console.log("10x max number value parsed as BigInt: " + BigInt(BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE).toString() + '0'));
```